# Less CSS extract list appropriately

Tags: css, less, frontend

So I have a parametric mixin (.calculateWidth) that calculates width based on child element width. I want this mixin to take data such as:

```
@heading: heading (class), none (width), 0 0 20px (padding), 0 (margin);
@imgContainer: imgContainer, 300px, 0 20px, 0;
@textContainer: textContainer, 330px, 0 20px, 0;
```

...and find all the values it needs to calculate width (width1, width2, padding l/r, etc.)

Here is what the function looks like when called:

```
.calculateWidth(container, @imgContainer, @textContainer, floated);
```

Now I want to be able to write the value for padding using any shorthand form I want (0 20px 0 or 0 20px, etc.) and for .calculateWidth to extract it properly.

The problem that I am having is that this requires a couple "& when" statements that capture the result in a variable:

```
& when(length(@padding1) = 1) {
    @p1-l: @p1;
}
& when(length(@padding1) = 2) {
    @p1-l: extract(@p1, 2);
}
& when(length(@padding1) = 3) {
    @p1-l: extract(@p1, 2);
}
& when(length(@padding1) = 4) {
    @p1-l: extract(@p1, 4);
}
```

But when I try to use "@p1-l" to calculate width, it won't work because of variable scope:

```
width: (@w1 + @p1-l + @p1-r) + (@w2 + @p2-l + @p2-r) + @m1-r;
```

I've been trying everything. Any suggestions would be GREATLY appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`& when` construction defines a ruleset (not a mixin) which does not expose its internal variables to the outer scope. I.e. you need to use a mixin instead, like this for example (use any suitable name instead of `.-`) :

```
// ...

.-();
.-() when(length(@padding1) = 1) {
    @p1-l: @p1;
}
.-() when(length(@padding1) = 2) {
    @p1-l: extract(@p1, 2);
}
.-() when(length(@padding1) = 3) {
    @p1-l: extract(@p1, 2);
}
.-() when(length(@padding1) = 4) {
    @p1-l: extract(@p1, 4);
}

// ...
```

Above can be simplified to:

```
// ...

.-(length(@padding1));
.-(1) {
    @p1-l: @p1;
}
.-(2) {
    @p1-l: extract(@p1, 2);
}
.-(3) {
    @p1-l: extract(@p1, 2);
}
.-(4) {
    @p1-l: extract(@p1, 4);
}

// ...
```

And finally all this can be simplified to just:

```
// ...

.-(length(@padding1));
.-(@i) {@p1-l: extract(@p1, @i)}
.-(1)  {@p1-l: @p1}

// ...
```